# How to speed up the send() method in scapy

Tags: python, networking, send, scapy

I tried to send 255 differnet arp packets via scapy with sendp and all those packets were sent in seconds, but when I try to send ICMP packets it takes a lot of time until every packet is being sent.... Can you tell me please how to send those ICMP packets as fast as the ARP packets?
Thanks

```
for ip in get_all_ip():
    pkt1 = Ether(dst = "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff", type = 2054)/ARP(pdst = ip)
    pkt2 = Ether()/IP(dst = ip)/ICMP()
    packets_ip.append(pkt2)
    packets_p.append(pkt1)
sendp(packets_p) # Takes seconds
send(packets_ip)  # Takes a lot of time
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to do, but you are using `send()` with Ethernet packets. `send()` is used to send "layer 3" packets (e.g., `IP()` or `IPv6()`).